# Neural network regression: the Difference between training MAE and cross-validation results

Tags: k-fold

I'm working on a regression task using a neural network implemented in Keras. I trained the model for 1000 epochs, and on the last epoch, I obtained a mean absolute error (MAE) value of 3.8  However, when I performed cross-validation using cross_validate function, the resulting MAE values are much higher.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense

# ... (data preprocessing steps)

def build_regressor():
    # ... (model architecture definition)

regressor = KerasRegressor(build_fn=build_regressor, batch_size=10, epochs=1000)
scoring = ['neg_mean_absolute_error']
results = cross_validate(estimator=regressor, X=x_train_scaled, y=y_train, cv=5, scoring=scoring)
```

and this the output of this code :
[image]

as you see in the last epoch : mae ( mean absolute error ) = 3.8

The results I obtained from the cross-validation (-results['test_neg_mean_absolute_error']) show higher MAE values than the training MAE of 3.8 from the last epoch. I expected the cross-validation results to be similar or at least in the same range as the training MAE.

this is the unexpected result :
`-results['test_neg_mean_absolute_error']`
array([13.15011832,  9.84094066,  9.6454553 , 11.37415547,
13.12120939])

I'm wondering why there is such a difference between the training MAE and the cross-validation results, especially considering the low MAE achieved on the last epoch. Am I missing something or should I consider other factors when interpreting the cross-validation results?

Answer (score 0):

The discrepancy between the training mean absolute error (MAE) and the cross-validation results can be attributed to several factors. Cross-validation provides a more reliable estimate of the model's generalization performance by evaluating it on different subsets of the data. Neural networks can exhibit high variability in performance due to sensitivity to initial weights and biases. The model's performance on the last epoch may have resulted from overfitting. Hyperparameter tuning is crucial to avoid overfitting or underfitting. Analyzing the distribution of MAE values from cross-validation and performing hyperparameter tuning can provide a better understanding of the model's performance.